# Capture output of complexheatmap as a grob?

Tags: r, graphics, bioconductor

[`ComplexHeatmap`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ComplexHeatmap.html) is a god sent tool with respect to heatmaps as a plot type. As one of the authors of [`multipanelfigure`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multipanelfigure/index.html), I fail, however, to find a straight forward solution to capture the produced heatmap output in a `grid::grob` object for easy inclusion into scientific compound figures as generated by [`multipanelfigure`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multipanelfigure/index.html).

Any pointers?

Joh

Comment: Now also added as an issue/feature request to `ComplexHeatmap`'s `github` repo ([here](https://github.com/jokergoo/ComplexHeatmap/issues/110).

Comment: `?grid.grab` : `g <- grid.grabExpr(print(Heatmap(mat)))` seems to cpature the plot using example from `?Heatmap`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user20650 points out above, `grid::grid.grabExpr` does the job.

As of version 0.10.0 [`multipanelfigure`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/multipanelfigure/index.html) cleanly supports inclusion of output from [`ComplexHeatmap`](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ComplexHeatmap.html).